# How to extract specific value in bash

Tags: bash

I got this input and I try to extract "out_of_stock". I want to extract the value between "code":" and ","days_. Consider "{"id":5,"text":"Stoc epuizat","code":"out_of_stock","days_estimation":0" as any other string ignore the json appearace.. Also I would like to assign it to a variable in bash

```
$ cat input_test.html
availability: {"id":5,"text":"Stoc epuizat","code":"out_of_stock","days_estimation":0
```

```
$ sed -n "s/.*code\":\"(.*)\",\"days.*/\1/p" input_test.html > output_test.html
sed: -e expression #1, char 29: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

Answer (score -1):

<s>If `out_of_stock` you want, just:</s>

```
$ grep -o out_of_stock input_test.html
out_of_stock
```

**Edit**:  Using grep and PCRE lookaround (where available):

```
$ grep -oP "(?<=\"code\":\").*(?=\",\"days_)" input_test.html
out_of_stock
```

Comment: This doesn't help me. The value may differ I would like to extract what is between code":" and ","days and assign it to a variable

Comment: Thank you for asking a proper question. Updated my answer.

Comment: I'd assume that the downvoter saw the first version and hasn't been here to notice the updates since.

Comment: It was downvoted after the edit. But anything for a good show and tell.

Comment: Your attitude says a lot about the downvoting, but I think you may try to focus on giving a proper answer too. How does your regular expression work? The way it is presented now does not help other people.

Comment: It was a proper answer to the given question. What comes to the standing answer, _lookaround_ and _PCRE_ should tell everything and if not, they are great catchwords to google.